# ¿Porque cuando creo SASS no se añade a mi app.scss?

Tags: html, sass, gulp

`function watchArchivo()  { watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', css) }`

Esta es la funcion con la que mando a mi archivo app.css pero no detecta el header de mi pagina

Comment: Resuelto!!!!!!!

Comment: Si lograste resolver tu problema, **ponlo como respuesta**, y cuando pase el tiempo correspondiente, [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer). También, a pesar de que ya resolviste el inconveniente, haz más descriptiva tu pregunta.